# Arduino Uno-style Reset Circuit

Tags: arduino, reset

I recently took an oscilloscope to a reset circuit on a new board I am working on (derivative of [WildFire](http://wildfire.wickeddevice.com)). Nothing earth shattering here, U6 is an Atmel ATMega1284P (VCC=5V), and U8 is an FTDI FT231X (VCCIO=3.3V, 5V-tolerant). The relevant parts of the schematic are:

[image]

and

[image]

and here is a scope trace of what happens when DTR goes low on the FTDI chip.

[image]

The blue line is DTR, the yellow line is RESET (never mind the labels). When DTR goes low, it looks to me from the scope, that the RESET signal doesn't get all the way to GND, reaching a minimum at the cusp of about 1.72V before 'discharging' back to 5V.

The thing is, the ATMega1284P is certainly resetting as intended, but I'm concerned that it's not reaching a low enough voltage to be in spec for a reset. The datasheet says that Vlow for RESET is 0.1*Vcc, which would be 0.5V @ Vcc=5V, and I'm a good 1V above that apparently.

So, (1) can you explain why RESET doesn't get all the way to GND, and (2) can you suggest a fix, without changing the design fundamentally, that *will* get RESET to drop below 0.5V when DTR transitions from 3.3V to GND? I'm imagining the shape of this fix to be something like change R11 to a different value, or change C24 to a different value. Or some combination theretofore.

Or am I just seeing a measurement artifact? You can't really see it behind the cursor bubble on the scope trace, but when DTR transitions from GND to 3.3V, it looks like RESET exhibits an inverse signal, rising to about 6.48V and then 'discharging' to 5V. I'm not seeing how that is a predicted outcome of the circuits in play here.

**EDIT**
Writing a question down thoughtfully makes it stare you in the face sometimes. It's because DTR is at 3.3V and RESET is at 5V. So the most that C24 can pull down reset is by 3.3V, which leaves a residue of 1.7V.

So the updated question is how would *you* fix this? Pull the ATmega1284P reset up to 3.3V instead of 5V?

Comment: How would the two signal traces be different if the pins are connected directly? That indicates there is some extra circuitry that you left out. What sits between `RESET/2.3E` and  `RESET/7.7B`?

Comment: @BrendanSimpson Nothing those nets are identical, they are just on different pages of my schematic. DTR and RESET are coupled through C24 (in series).

Comment: Is your yellow scope channel AC coupled?

Comment: Read the Atmega datasheet carefully, looking for logic levels applying to the Reset pin, at VCC=5V. It'll likely confirm that 3.3V is unambiguously Logic 1 in which case your EDIT idea is fine.

Comment: @BrendanSimpson nah it's DC coupled.

Comment: @BrianDrummond datasheet suggests Vih for RESET is at least 0.9 * VCC = 4.5V, no dice.

Comment: It just looks suspiciously like AC coupling. I mean, if your probes are literally connected to the same net, there is no reason they would disagree like this unless the yellow channel was AC coupled. The other reason would be that there are some components between the DTR pin and the Reset pin

Comment: @BrendanSimpson the probes are connected to different nets, DTR (blue) and RESET (yellow). These nets are on opposite sides of capacitor C24.

Comment: Oh, duh. I missed that, I was looking on my phone. That explains why the yellow trace is AC coupled. I see from your edit you figured out the why portion. Why cant you change the VCCIO on the FTDI to 5V? You could use a 3.3V pull-up on the reset line but  that's probably not the best idea from a noise immunity standpoint, especially on the reset pin.  I'd also put  a clamping diode in parallel with the reset pull-up. When DTR goes high, there will be a fairly high voltage transient on that pin. The duration is probably short enough to not cause any damage, but better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I recall having exactly the same issue on a recent design with the FT231X. I'll have to check tomorrow on our original issue and solution but I reckon the answer is to reprogram the ftdi chip to invert the DTR function (maybe, or maybe you need to use a different pin) and use it to drive an open drain FET on the reset net.

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I have completley mis-remembered our issue. It was with using CBUS3 as a power enable on a FT230X (not full handshaking version). Still, if you can invert your signal the suggestion should work.

I have to say I'm a little confused though, the DTR functionality is for RS232 handshaking and I can't see on the datasheet how you can use this for reset?

Comment: It's an old Arduino trick. The capacitor circuit is just meant to convert a falling edge on DTR (which I suppose is built into USB driver) into a brief low blip on the RESET line.

Comment: That is to say, when you open a terminal program on a computer, it induces a reset.

Comment: @vicatcu Right, trick you say, sounds like a bodge to me ;)

Comment: Alas, it's used prolifically in that world.

Comment: It does look like you can configure DTR to invert, so that's probably my most straightforward fix. Invert and add an open drain FET with a pull-up to 5V into the design.